# I Know I have correct KeyHash but still get remote_app_id does not match stored id

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

I am sure i have the right **Key Hash** having used facebook's suggested code to get it from logcat, i have removed the log in code i wrote and copy/pasted the code directly from the **facebook's** `sessionloginsampleactivity` to ensure i hadn't made any programming errors, yet I am still getting:

> W/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(504): com.facebook.orca.protocol.base.ApiException: remote_app_id does not match stored id

The login screen comes up and asks if you want to allow this app permission, but upon pressing **OK** nothing changes and the login button is still visible rather than it saying logout.  I know the code works because it works properly on the emulated device as i also know the debug key hash.  I read facebook documentation about this error but it will not go away! Help!

Comment: I got the same problem with Android Jellybean. The same app works ok on lower Android version though. What Android version are you using to get this warning?

Comment: @Fre this exception is due to wrong openssl,please see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/16212920/1939564

Comment: @MuhammadBabar: I am also getting the same error but with other's emulator. Using debug key I am able to login using emulator in my environment but the same does not work in my colleague's emulator and he gets an error,  com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiException: remote_app_id does not match stored id. Any idea?

Comment: @MuhammadBabar: I am getting this exception, when fb native app is being used for authentication. For browser authentication(when fb native app is not presinstalled) it works well.

Comment: @Kaps Yes thats the problem with your openssl, i was also facing the same problem, i solved it by downloading the correct openssl, please see my comment above to get the link to download openssl and your problem will vanish away :)

Comment: I have already used openssl from the link you have provided. This also generates the same key, which I was using previously using the link shared in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/.