# error: remote_app_id does not match stored id with correct heyhash

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

06-02 23:20:54.909: W/fb4a(:):BlueServiceQueue(6282): com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiException: remote_app_id does not match stored id

I have this warning with the samples of facebook sdk 3.0.1, I have the correct keyhash but the status of login don´t change when I login with the button, by the way the session is null, don't mind what sometimes do click in the login button. I work with Java 1.6

I don't have any problem if I open de session like Hackbook sample? I see that some function are deprecated, and the app that I'm doing I need to up at Market.

Comment: this may be due to wrong openssl you have downloaded, please refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/a/16212920/1939564

Comment: I use the Muhammad Babar solution and it works!!
http://stackoverflow.com/a/16212920/537023