# Android facebook log in failed remote app id does not match stored id

Tags: social-networking, facebook-login

I have given the app Id and package name in my Android manifest file.

In the facebook also i have provided Package name, class name and Key hashes.

Whenever i am logging into facebook it is giving me this error.

facebook login failed : remote app id does not match stored id.

I have searched in stackoverflow and everywhere it is written that to solve this problem you have to change openssl and I dont know what is openssl.

Comment: Its not the app id problem because i have tried with 2 different app ids and still the same problem.

Comment: please check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/16212920/1939564 and you also need to follow this tutorial https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/ so can get an idea what openssl is