# Facebook Invalid Hash key

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

i developing an android app with Facebook auth. I all the time get an error with invalid key hash .the key hash doesn't match any stored .I already removed 
couple times an app from Facebook and changed Hash keys and it still appears when i trying to auth with Facebook.(I don't have enough reputation to upload a picture with an error).I tried already everything that posted here, and its not helping me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16212920/1939564

Comment: did already, but it stil didnt help.

Comment: how did you get your hash-key ?

Answer (score 0):

You should integrate this `OnCreate()` method and run the application and logcat keyhash: copy to facebook developer key hashes.

```
try{
    PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                           "your.package.name",
                           PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
    for (Signature signature : info.signatures){
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        md.update(signature.toByteArray());
        Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
    }
}
catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e){

}
catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e){

}
```