# Invalid app id while trying to log in using Facebook

Tags: android, facebook

I am developing an Android app using Parse and Facebook SDKs. I have implemented Facebook login successfully and everything worked fine before that error came few days ago.

It happens when I press the login button and shows me an error saying **Invalid app id xxxxxxx**. Note that the **xxxxxxx** that they are showing is different then my app id on Facebook (which am using in my string.xml and manifest.xml and which was working before).

For the reason, I have no idea, it just came suddenly not working with no change on project.

So I searched for the problem and met the same question many times (specially here on Stack Overflow) and tried to fix it with the answers but no answer did the help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16212920/1939564

Comment: Are you obfuscating your code? Then your app id could get obfuscated (and changed) too.

Comment: Thankyou all, Muhammad Babar, how can i use the openssl to fix the problem ?. Aster, bfuscating your code? what do you mean ?

Comment: Were you able to solve your issue? You will need to ensure you are using the correct Key Hash and Android Package Name information as well in your Facebook App Settings.

Comment: Ckeck if this fixes it http://stackoverflow.com/a/31963116/2390592