# Facebook api invalid app iD

Tags: android, facebook

I have some problem with facebook SKD. I get invalid app ID when I am trying to login. Can you please help me figure out what the problem is?

[image]

My facebook app looks like this:

[image]

Manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="70208723325****" />
</application>
```

Comment: Is your Facebook app public?

Comment: No, just now starting develop it. It is not on play or any other place

Comment: Did you set the KeyHashes? In you screenshot there is no keys.

Comment: I have now added keyHash and same error

Comment: Follow that tutorial from the documentaion:https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#release-key-hash

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone has this problem, I fixed it with not putting the appId value directly in the manifest file. Instead you should put it in strings and then in manifest you put

`<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>`

It's strange but it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

1.Try to change the facebook status and review as yes.
2.Enter the [Key hash](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#release-key-hash) value (Setting -> keyhash).

[image: Change the facebook status and review]